# CSS styling for a Kendo TreeView

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-treeview

I've got some Bootstrap css styling issues on several Kendo TreeView widgets I'm rendering.

Basically, I have a wizard which the user will navigate through, and on one of the pages I'm display two Kendo TreeView widgets. The user will be able to drag items from the left "source" tree onto their own customized data tree.

Right now the datasource is the same, but that doesn't matter.

The important thing is that the sprite folder image on my left navbar tree is getting hidden every time I navigate to my wizard page which contains the dual treeviews.

I'd like to style of the TreeView so it doesn't interfere with another tree widget in my sidebar. The sprite folder icon is getting hidden in my sidebar tree once I click on the "+" icon which changes my page.

[image]

[image]

Here is the reportmaint.html page which renders when I click on the "+" icon in sidebar.html (see screen image below). Keep in mind that the reportmaint view contains the left and right TreeViews:

```
<section data-report-wizard id="reportmaint-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="reportmaint as vm">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container-fluid">                                  
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="widget wlightblue">
                    <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.wizardStep}}" subtitle="" allow-collapse="true"></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <div class="clearfix">

<!-- Wizard steps 1 thru 4 omiteed for brevity -->

   <div id="wizard4" class="reportwizard">
   <div class="row-fluid">
        <h3>Choose KRIs</h3>
        <h4>Selected: {{vm.selectedItem.text}}</h4>
        <div class="col-sm-6">                      <!-- kendo TreeView widgets -->
            <span id="treeview-left" kendo-tree-view="tree"
                   k-options="vm.treeOptions"
                     k-datasource="vm.kriDataSource1"                                                       
                   k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)"    
               </span>
        </div>                                
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <span id="treeview-right" kendo-tree-view="tree"
                   k-options="vm.treeOptions"
                     k-data-source="vm.kriDataSource2"                                                       
                   k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)">
               </span>
        </div>                                            
     </div>                                                
    <div class="buttons">                                        
      <button class="goto5" ng-click="vm.wizardStep='Report Dimensions'">Next</button>
      <button class="cancel-btn backto3" ng-click="vm.wizardStep='Report Dimensions'">Back</button>
      <button class="cancel-btn close-popup">Close</button>
    </div>
 </div>
   </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

css code in reportmaint.html :

```
<style scoped>
    #treeview-left, #treeview-right  {
        color:#000;
    }
    .k-textbox {
        width: 11.8em;
    }

    .demo-section {
        width: 700px;
    }

    .reportwizard {
        width: 510px;
        height: 323px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px 20px 20px 170px;            
    }

    .reportwizard h3 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .reportwizard ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .reportwizard li {
        margin: 7px 0 0 0;
    }
    textarea {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 90px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .required {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .accept, .status {
        padding-left: 90px;
    }

    .valid {
        color: green;
    }

    .invalid {
        color: red;
    }
    span.k-tooltip {
        margin-left: 6px;
    }        
</style>
```

and my sidebar.html with css code which styles the left TreeView "reports" menu :

```
 <div style="float:left;">
        <span id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="tree"                           
            k-options="vm.treeOptions"
            k-data-source="vm.reportsTree"
            k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)">
        </span>        
    </div>

<style scoped>        
    .k-treeview .k-plus, .k-treeview .k-minus, .k-treeview .k-plus-disabled, .k-treeview .k-minus-disabled {
        background-image: url("../../Content/kendo/2014.1.624/Uniform/sprite.png");
        background-position: -161px -192px; 
        width: 10px;
        height: 11px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left:-10px;
    }
    #treeview_tv_active > div > span.k-icon.k-plus {
        background-image: url("../../Content/kendo/2014.1.624/Uniform/sprite.png");
        background-position: -176px -192px; 
        width: 10px;
        height: 11px;
    }
    #treeview_tv_active > div > span.k-icon.k-minus {
        background-image:url("../../Content/kendo/2014.1.624/Uniform/sprite.png");
        background-position: -177px -211px; 
        width: 10px;
        height: 11px;
    }        
    #treeview  {
        color: #fff;    /* white */
    }
</style>
```

Again, once I click on the "+" sign I navigate to reportmain.html. This is when the sidebar treeview styling inadvertently changes; and the background-image folder icon gets hidden.

thanks.
Bob